# Mass update Knowledge Articles with Data Categories

Tags: knowledge, data, field-update, categories

Is there any possible way to update an existing set of knowledge articles to include specific data categories without manually going into each one?

Can this be achieved with data Loader?

Comment: I'm interested in the answer, too (using Data Loader, not the article import wizard). https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YYZsAAO, http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Is-there-way-export-all-3784290.S.107563727 and https://sites.google.com/site/ezrakenigsberg/blog/migratingknowledge give some hints, but I 'd like to have a definite answer.

Answer (score 2):

https://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/knowledge_article_importer_02csv.htm

This is a standard article from salesforce and clearly guides on how to use the article importer to load CSV

datacategorygroup .Products is column used to populate  Products if Product is the datacategory.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this  with data loader.

1.Make one .csv  file of articles having particular article type. In this file, One column will be having IDs of knowledge articles which you want to assign a data category. Name this column as ParentId.

2.second column will be DataCategoryGroupName.Write the name of active data category group name which you want to assign to the articles.

3.Third column will be dataCategoryName, which is the category name under data category group.

After making .csv file as mentioned above, please import to datacategoryselection:Article_type_name object in data loader and map with appropriate fields.All the required categories will be assigned to articles after importing it.Please select this as best answer if this answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers were written in the days of Classic Knowledge, here's an update for Lightning Knowledge:

**To see your existing Data Category assignments, if any**

```
SELECT DataCategoryGroupName, DataCategoryName, ParentId, Parent.Title, Parent.VersionNumber 
 FROM Knowledge__DataCategorySelection
```

*where Parent refers to a `Knowledge__kav` object (Knowledge article version)*

In Lightning Knowledge, there is no concept called `ArticleType` as referenced in the [Knowledge Article Help article](https://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/knowledge_article_importer_02csv.htm)

**To see your existing Knowledge Articles:**

```
SELECT Id, RecordType.Name,Title,UrlName,VersionNumber 
   FROM Knowledge__kav
```

**So, to mass insert (assign) new data categories, you basically need to construct a CSV that looks like this:**

```
ParentId                 DataCategoryGroupName     DataCategoryName
<id of a Knowledge_kav>  <aDataCategoryGroupName>  <aDataCategoryName>
```

Example:

```
ParentId                 DataCategoryGroupName     DataCategoryName
ka0....                  North America             WidgetFAQ
ka0....                  North America             WidgetTroubleshooting
ka0....                  EMEA                      WidgetFAQ
ka0....                  EMEA                      GDPRStuff
```

and insert into `Data Category Selection: Knowledge` (API name = `Knowledge__DataCategorySelection`)

- [Knowledge Object Model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_development_object_model.htm)
- [DataCategoryGroup hierarchy (Metadata API)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_datacategorygroup.htm?search_text=datacategorygroup)